# NextJs - Getting error #426 when app load first time in a new browser and in production only

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am getting weird error in production only and that's also happen first time when you load in a new browser or after deleting all caches. I am using `nextjs 13.2.3` and hosted the site on Vercel.

See below screenshot
[image: error message]

Below is the error from console.

```js
Error: Minified React error #426; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=426 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at oL (framework-73b8966a3c579ab0.js:9:98070)
    at oF (framework-73b8966a3c579ab0.js:9:99006)
    at ox (framework-73b8966a3c579ab0.js:9:95740)
    at oC (framework-73b8966a3c579ab0.js:9:96129)
    at r4 (framework-73b8966a3c579ab0.js:9:44778)
    at framework-73b8966a3c579ab0.js:9:93632
a5 @ framework-73b8966a3c579ab0.js:9
main-e4be697f641c1f12.js:1 Error: Minified React error #426; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=426 for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and additional helpful warnings.
    at oL (framework-73b8966a3c579ab0.js:9:98070)
    at oF (framework-73b8966a3c579ab0.js:9:99006)
    at ox (framework-73b8966a3c579ab0.js:9:95740)
    at oC (framework-73b8966a3c579ab0.js:9:96129)
    at r4 (framework-73b8966a3c579ab0.js:9:44778)
    at framework-73b8966a3c579ab0.js:9:93632
K @ main-e4be697f641c1f12.js:1
main-e4be697f641c1f12.js:1 A client-side exception has occurred, see here for more info: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/client-side-exception-occurred
K @ main-e4be697f641c1f12.js:1
```

I visited the page https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?invariant=426 and it complain the following

```html
A component suspended while responding to synchronous input. This will cause the UI to be replaced with a loading indicator. To fix, updates that suspend should be wrapped with startTransition.
```

I am not using React suspense. Not sure why this error comes only in a fresh browser and that's too on production. After first refresh everything works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue while using i18next this way:

i18n.ts

```
import i18n from 'i18next';

i18n
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)
  .use(Backend)
  .init(config)

export default i18n
```

App.tsx

```
import i18n from '../i18n';

const App = ({ Component }) => {
  return (
     <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
        {Component}
      </I18nextProvider>
  )
}
```

And the issue was that the `init` method of `i18n` was async and in some cases wasn't loaded so the `I18nextProvider` returned result that wasn't expected.
So, the solution is to wait until `i18n` is loaded:

App.tsx

```
import i18nConfig from '../i18n';

const App = ({ Component }) => {
  const [isI18nInitialised, setIsI18nInitialised] = useState(false);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    async function initializeI18n() {
      await i18n
        .use(LanguageDetector)
        .use(initReactI18next)
        .use(Backend)
        .init(i18nConfig);
      setIsI18nInitialised(true);
    }

    initializeI18n();
  }, []);
  
  return (
    {isI18nInitialised && (
      <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
        {Component}
      </I18nextProvider>
    )}
  )
}
```